# text on grid gallery with mouseover effect

Tags: html, css

I want to make a grid 3x3 gallery with a mouseover text effect for each image. (only with HTML and CSS)
But It doesn't work for each image, it works for the entire grid section.
I don't know why.
The text should appear on each picture.
Please help me with this. Thanks!

HTML

```
    <section>
  <div class="favorite" id="favorite">

    <div class="favorite-item" id="favorite-item">
      <div class="grid1" id="grid1">
        <img src="fav01.jpeg" alt="favorite img">
          <div class="imgtext">
            <div class="text-1"> Activity </div>
          </div></img>
        <img src="fav02.jpeg" alt="favorite img">
          <div class="imgtext">
            <div class="text-1"> Snowboarding  </div>
          </div></img>
        <img src="fav03.jpeg" alt="favorite img">
          <div class="imgtext">
            <div class="text-1"> Art Museum  </div>
          </div></img>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="favorite-item" id="favorite-item">
      <div class="grid2" id="grid2">
        <img src="fav04.jpeg" alt="favorite img">
          <div class="imgtext">
            <div class="text-2"> Halloween party  </div>
          </div>
        <img src="fav05.jpeg" alt="favorite img">
          <div class="imgtext">
            <div class="text-2"> Wine  </div>
          </div>
        <img src="fav06.jpeg" alt="favorite img">
          <div class="imgtext">
            <div class="text-2"> Travel </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="favorite-item" id="favorite-item">
      <div class="grid3" id="grid3">
        <img src="fav07.jpeg" alt="favorite img">
          <div class="imgtext">
            <div class="text-3"> Picnic </div>
          </div>
        <img src="fav08.jpeg" alt="favorite img">
          <div class="imgtext">
            <div class="text-3"> Music  </div>
          </div>
        <img src="fav09.jpeg" alt="favorite img">
          <div class="imgtext">
            <div class="text-1"> Wakeboarding  </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


</section>
```

CSS

```
    .favorite {
        width: 70%;
        margin: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        grid-gap: 3px 3px;
}
.favorite-item {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        position: relative;
}
.favorite-item img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: contain;

}


.text-1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}


.text-1:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}



@media (min-width: 640px) {
    .favorite {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
          gap: 3px;
    }
    .grid1 {
          display:  block;
          row-gap: 3px;
    }
    .grid2 {
          display: block;
          row-gap: 3px;
    }
    .grid3 {
          display: block;
          row-gap: 3px;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not put another `tag` in `<img/>`

```css
    .favorite {
        width: 70%;
        margin: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        grid-gap: 3px 3px;
}
.favorite-item {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        position: relative;
}
.favorite-item img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: contain;

}

.img-item{
  position:relative;
}


.text-1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}


.text-1:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
[class^="grid"]{
 display:flex;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {
    .favorite {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
          gap: 3px;
    }
    .grid1 {
          display:  block;
          row-gap: 3px;
    }
    .grid2 {
          display: block;
          row-gap: 3px;
    }
    .grid3 {
          display: block;
          row-gap: 3px;
    }
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="favorite" id="favorite">
  
      <div class="favorite-item" id="favorite-item">
        <div class="grid1" id="grid1">
          <div class="img-item">
                  <img src="https://thumb.cloud.mail.ru/weblink/thumb/xw1/cdoC/d646Tf3gQ/10/10/1010341404/1010341404_450.jpg" alt="favorite img"/>
            <div class="imgtext">
              <div class="text-1"> Activity </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="img-item">
                 <img src="https://thumb.cloud.mail.ru/weblink/thumb/xw1/cdoC/d646Tf3gQ/10/10/1010341404/1010341404_450.jpg" alt="favorite img"/>
            <div class="imgtext">
              <div class="text-1"> Snowboarding  </div>
            </div>
          </div>
   
        <div class="img-item">
            <img src="https://thumb.cloud.mail.ru/weblink/thumb/xw1/cdoC/d646Tf3gQ/10/10/1010341404/1010341404_450.jpg" alt="favorite img" />
            <div class="imgtext">
              <div class="text-1"> Art Museum  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="favorite-item" id="favorite-item">
        <div class="grid2" id="grid2">
          <div class="img-item">
                  <img src="https://thumb.cloud.mail.ru/weblink/thumb/xw1/cdoC/d646Tf3gQ/10/10/1010341404/1010341404_450.jpg" alt="favorite img"/>
            <div class="imgtext">
              <div class="text-1"> Activity </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="img-item">
                 <img src="https://thumb.cloud.mail.ru/weblink/thumb/xw1/cdoC/d646Tf3gQ/10/10/1010341404/1010341404_450.jpg" alt="favorite img"/>
            <div class="imgtext">
              <div class="text-1"> Snowboarding  </div>
            </div>
          </div>
   
        <div class="img-item">
            <img src="https://thumb.cloud.mail.ru/weblink/thumb/xw1/cdoC/d646Tf3gQ/10/10/1010341404/1010341404_450.jpg" alt="favorite img" />
            <div class="imgtext">
              <div class="text-1"> Art Museum  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="favorite-item" id="favorite-item">
        <div class="grid3" id="grid3">
          <div class="img-item">
                  <img src="https://thumb.cloud.mail.ru/weblink/thumb/xw1/cdoC/d646Tf3gQ/10/10/1010341404/1010341404_450.jpg" alt="favorite img"/>
            <div class="imgtext">
              <div class="text-1"> Activity </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="img-item">
                 <img src="https://thumb.cloud.mail.ru/weblink/thumb/xw1/cdoC/d646Tf3gQ/10/10/1010341404/1010341404_450.jpg" alt="favorite img"/>
            <div class="imgtext">
              <div class="text-1"> Snowboarding  </div>
            </div>
          </div>
   
        <div class="img-item">
            <img src="https://thumb.cloud.mail.ru/weblink/thumb/xw1/cdoC/d646Tf3gQ/10/10/1010341404/1010341404_450.jpg" alt="favorite img" />
            <div class="imgtext">
              <div class="text-1"> Art Museum  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  
    </div>
  
  
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify this a little bit.

The idea is that you want six containers in a grid. Inside each container you have an image and a caption. The caption is absolutely positioned over the top of the image.

Then when you hover over any of these containers, set the opacity of the caption inside the container to 1.

(I've reduced the min-width slightly so you can preview it in the answer)

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 3px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
  div>div {
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
}

.container {
  position:relative;
}

.container img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  
}

.container .caption {
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  color:#fff;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  opacity:0;
  transition:opacity 0.3s;
}

.container:hover .caption {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://kb.rspca.org.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/golder-retriever-puppy.jpeg" />
    <div class="caption">I'm a dog!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://kb.rspca.org.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/golder-retriever-puppy.jpeg" />
    <div class="caption">I'm a dog!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://kb.rspca.org.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/golder-retriever-puppy.jpeg" />
    <div class="caption">I'm a dog!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://kb.rspca.org.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/golder-retriever-puppy.jpeg" />
    <div class="caption">I'm a dog!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://kb.rspca.org.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/golder-retriever-puppy.jpeg" />
    <div class="caption">I'm a dog!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://kb.rspca.org.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/golder-retriever-puppy.jpeg" />
    <div class="caption">I'm a dog!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://kb.rspca.org.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/golder-retriever-puppy.jpeg" />
    <div class="caption">I'm a dog!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://kb.rspca.org.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/golder-retriever-puppy.jpeg" />
    <div class="caption">I'm a dog!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://kb.rspca.org.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/golder-retriever-puppy.jpeg" />
    <div class="caption">I'm a dog!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```